# Get CSS variables applied to an element

Tags: javascript, webkit, css-variables

In chrome / chromium, I would like to list all the CSS variables (variable names and values) applied on an HTML element. The following code works in Firefox but seams to be unsupported in webkit browsers. Is there a possible workaround?

```js
let style = getComputedStyle(document.body);
for (let i = 0; i < style.length; i++) {
  let prop = style[i]
  if(prop.includes("--")){
    let val = style.getPropertyValue(prop)
    document.body.innerHTML = "Works in Firefox but not in Chromium:<br>"
    document.body.innerHTML += prop+" "+val
  }
}
```

```css
:root{
  --c:lime;
}
body{
  background:var(--c);
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1316 might be helpful?

Comment: `style.getPropertyValue('--c') // lime` works in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Instructive, thank you! And yes, `getPropertyValue` works but in my case I don’t know the names of the variables, I need to retrieve it.

Comment: What about https://css-tricks.com/how-to-get-all-custom-properties-on-a-page-in-javascript/?

Comment: @evolutionxbox That solve my issue indeed! Thank you. I will answer my post.

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem:

```js
const isSameDomain = (styleSheet) => {
  if (!styleSheet.href) {
    return true;
  }

  return styleSheet.href.indexOf(window.location.origin) === 0;
};

const isStyleRule = (rule) => rule.type === 1;

const getCSSCustomPropIndex = () =>
  [...document.styleSheets].filter(isSameDomain).reduce(
    (finalArr, sheet) =>
      finalArr.concat(
        [...sheet.cssRules].filter(isStyleRule).reduce((propValArr, rule) => {
          const props = [...rule.style]
            .map((propName) => [
              propName.trim(),
              rule.style.getPropertyValue(propName).trim()
            ])
            .filter(([propName]) => propName.indexOf("--") === 0);

          return [...propValArr, ...props];
        }, [])
      ),
    []
  );

document.body.innerHTML = getCSSCustomPropIndex()
```

```css
html {
  --c: lime;
}

 body {
  background:var(--c);
}
```

Thank you @evolutionxbox for pointing the [solution](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-get-all-custom-properties-on-a-page-in-javascript/).